# how to save a variable into the stack or in the memory

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am working to enable and disable a cheat for some game with a press of a button and got it working at some point.

The problem am facing is when the button is kept pressed the cheat works fine, but then once I let go of that button the cheat is no longer active .

The question is how to make it save the value of 0x02 once the button is pressed.

```
  Code Cave address 0x015F3800

015F3800 push r8
015F3802 movabs r8, 0x20219d1c4 <-- Buttons Address, (movabs) move absolute memory address value into r8
015F380C mov r8,[r8]       
015F380F cmp r8, 0x02 <-- r8 = 0 if nothing is pressed and when L3 is pressed r8 = 2
015F3813 jnz 0x015F3823 <-- ZF is set to 1 if L3 is pressed and ones i get hit HP gos to full, otherwise its clear (0)
015F3815 mov [rbx+0x1e68], ax <-- AX has max HP, modified code
015F381C pop r8
015F381E jmp 0xA161BB <-- return address, if L3 is preesed the rest of the code below will be ignored
015F3823 mov [rbx+0x1e68], cx <-- Original code, if L3 is not preesed the code continue as normal
015F382A pop r8
015F382C jmp 0xA161BB <-- return address
```

I'm not sure if this is the right place to post my question, so please feel free to delete it if it violates your forum rules
I have been learning amd64 assembly for the last few months until I got stuck.

Comment: off-topic: If you used `rax`, you could use `movabs rax, [0x20219d1c4]` for the `mov rax, moffs64` load encoding with a 64-bit absolute address.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html.  Also you could `pop` after the `cmp`, before the `jnz`

Comment: Not clear what you're asking.  Does this code run every game update cycle?  If you need something to survive between runs of this code to record if the cheat button has ever been pressed, you need some static storage somewhere.  You can't use the stack for the same reason a non-`static` local variable in C can't record anything across function calls.  Some storage in a page near your code-cave, using a RIP-relative addressing mode, would make sense if I'm understanding you correctly.  Don't put it within 2k of your code, that will cause self-modifying-code pipeline nukes.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Its just button toggle to turn things on and off, also i have tried some of what you have mentioned in your comment like movabs rax, [0x20219d1c4] it looks totally legit but the debugger am I using doesn't like it and i get crash call and it changed to mova eax, [0x20219d1c4] that make me wonder why it accepted it the code in 1st place unless my code is a big mess

Comment: also i get crash call when i try pop after the cmp, before the jnz, but after jnz works fine i have managed to save a byte somewhere in the eboot ones the functions of the player hp get executed it may help latter, never imagined it's going to be that hard and quite challenging